# Low brightness: Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ati, 13.04, brightness

I recently dual booted my Windows 8 with Ubuntu 13.04. The first thing that came to my notice was that the brightness was too low. I increased the brightness to maximum from system settings, but still, it remains low. I did not face any such issue with Ubuntu 12.10 that I had earlier.

Graphics Card: ATI Radeon 7730M

Laptop Model: Dell Inspiron 15R Turbo

So, is there a way to increase the brightness to the actual maximum?

Comment: which graphics drivers are you using? installing the proprietary drivers may help. `sudo apt-get install fglrx` or search fglrx in the software centre

Comment: I did what you said, the problem didn't get solved, instead my taskbar and dash pane dispaeared! Can I undo it??

Comment: You may need to reboot to ensure the newly installed drivers are loaded correctly. If you still have issues then they can be uninstalled by issuing the command "sudo apt-get purge fglrx" in a terminal. Ctrl+Alt+F1 will let you log into a command line if your graphics are really messed up. Be sure to reboot!

Comment: At least this is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1173059

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may need to use the acpi_osi='!Windows 2012' boot parameter

`sudo sed -i "s/quiet splash/quiet splash acpi_osi=\'\!Windows 2012\'/" /etc/default/grub;sudo update-grub;echo 'Reboot to apply'`

here is the command to undo that, if it makes it worse or does not do anything

`sudo sed -i "s/ acpi_osi=\'\!Windows 2012\'//" /etc/default/grub;sudo update-grub;echo 'Reboot to apply'`

Comment: Tried, not woking :(

Comment: I have added another workaround. Let us know.

Answer (score -2):

It could be possible that you may have to re-install the OS and junk if you are not going to loose a lot of stuff.

Comment: Is there a way around? I have a lot of stuff installed on my PC.